# Cannot open query window in SSMS

Tags: ssms, ssms-2017

Has anybody ever come across the SQL server error:

could not load file or assembly 'System.Globalization, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is what happens when I try to open a new query window, This had never happened before on the SSMS version 18.8 but tried to upgrade to version 19 but the error persists

Tried upgradeing to the latest version and that was unsuccessful

Comment: No, I've never encountered the error.

Comment: No stress thank you